# Is there a word for restricting the codomain of a function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Consider a function $f : A \rightarrow B$.

We can restrict the function to any subset of its domain. That is completely standard.

Sometimes we would also like to restrict the codomain of a function. Notably and obviously, the codomain must be large enough to contain the image $f(A)$ of the domain under $f$.

Is there a word or a formalism for restricting the codomain of a function?

Comment: It is basically factorization over the inclusion of the subset, isn't it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given a function $f : A \to B$ and a subset $V \subseteq B$ such that $f[A] \subseteq V$, the function $A \to V$ agreeing with $f$ is called the **corestriction** of $f$ to $V$.

The term is commonly used by category theorists such as myself (see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/corestriction) for example) since corestriction is quite literally the categorical dual of restriction.

See also [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29911/) on MathOverflow.

Comment: Thanks. I should have guessed that.